# pandas rename columns with method chaining

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe and did some feature engineering and now would like to change the column names.
I know how to change them if I do a new assignment but I would like to do it with method chaining. I tried the below (the `rename` row) but it doesn't work. How could I write it so it works?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,2,3,3,3], 'date': ['2021-10-12','2021-10-16','2021-10-15','2021-10-10','2021-10-19','2021-10-01'], 
                   'location':['up','up','down','up','up','down'], 
                   'code':[False, False, False, True, False, False]})

df = (df
     .assign(date = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.date))
     .assign(entries_per_ID = lambda x: x.groupby('ID').ID.transform('size'))
     .pivot_table(values=['entries_per_ID'], index=['ID','date','code'],
                   columns=['location'], aggfunc=np.max)
     .reset_index()
     #.rename(columns=lambda x: dict(zip(x.columns, ['_'.join(col).strip() if col[1]!='' else col[0] for col in x.columns.values])))
     )
```

This here works, but that's not how I would like to write it.

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() if col[1]!='' else col[0] for col in df.columns.values ]
```

Comment: From the source code, `rename` works on each level separately. You can't concatenate the different levels.

Comment: When using a function as argument for rename, that function expects a column name as argument, not a dataframe. That function is then applied to each name individually, so grouped names are not recognized.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Renaming columns in a chain

Use [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) along `axis=1`:

```
df.set_axis(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], axis=1)
```

#### Using `groupby`, `pivot`, `melt`, etc

If the new columns depend on some earlier step in the chain, combine [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) with [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html). For example, to capitalize pivoted columns in a chain:

- We **cannot** directly chain [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

  ```
  # does NOT work since df.columns are the original columns, not pivoted columns
  df.pivot(...).set_axis(df.columns.str.upper(), axis=1))
  ```
- But we **can** [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) the pivoted result into [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

  ```
  # does work since we've piped the pivoted df
  df.pivot(...).pipe(lambda piv: piv.set_axis(piv.columns.str.upper(), axis=1)))
  #                         ^    ^            ^
  ```

#### OP's example

Since OP has created a `pivot_table` and wants to conditionally collapse those pivoted MultiIndex, we [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) the `pivot_table` into the list comprehension:

```
(df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df.date))
   .assign(entries_per_ID=df.groupby('ID').ID.transform('size'))
   .pivot_table(index=['ID', 'date', 'code'],
                columns='location',
                values='entries_per_ID',
                aggfunc='max')
   .reset_index()
   .pipe(lambda piv: piv.set_axis(['_'.join(col).strip() if col[1] else col[0] for col in piv.columns],
                                  axis=1)))

#    ID        date   code  entries_per_ID_down  entries_per_ID_up
# 0   1  2021-10-12  False                  NaN                1.0
# 1   2  2021-10-15  False                  2.0                NaN
# 2   2  2021-10-16  False                  NaN                2.0
# 3   3  2021-10-01  False                  3.0                NaN
# 4   3  2021-10-10   True                  NaN                3.0
# 5   3  2021-10-19  False                  NaN                3.0
```